# Quarkus: request to URL given as string

Tags: java, rest, kotlin, quarkus

I want to make an HTTP request with Quarkus. However, the target URL is not known at compilation time, it will be composed from different parts at runtime.

Quarkus provides a way to build static REST clients like this:

```java
@Path("/v2")
@RegisterRestClient
public interface CountriesService {

    @GET
    @Path("/name/{name}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    Set<Country> getByName(@PathParam String name);
}
```

However, I am loking for something like the Python `requests` package:

```py
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
response = requests.get(url)
```

I am building the application in Kotlin, so all Java and Kotlin libraries should work.

What should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the MP REST Client defined in an interface, you can use the programmatic client creation API:

```
CountriesService remoteApi = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .baseUri("created at runtime url")
        .build(CountriesService.class);
remoteApi.getByName("");
```